# Is it possible to add two div boxes inside a html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I will make a html page, and see if it is possible to add 2 div boxes inside an html page with use of javascript ?

```
<h1>HEDER TEXT HERE</h1>
<p>Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibu magna mollis euismod.</p>
<h2 class="clear">Main contributors</h2>
<!-- START DIV CLASS="article" BOX HERE-->
<h3>Aenean lacinia bibendum.</h3>
<p class="clear">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget.</p>
<figure class="clear">
    <img src="img/klint-faaborg-chair.jpg" alt="Faaborg chair">
    <figcaption>Consectetur Fusce Quam</figcaption>
</figure>
<!-- Close DIV CLASS="article" BOX HERE-->

<!-- START DIV CLASS="article" BOX HERE-->
<h3>Magna Risus Bibendum</h3>
<p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Donec sed odio dui.Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Aenean lacinia bibendum.</p>
<figure>
    <img src="img/ph-artichoke-lamp.jpg" alt="Artichoke lamp">
    <figcaption>Consectetur Fusce Quam</figcaption>
</figure>
<!-- Close DIV CLASS="article" BOX HERE-->
<h2 class="clear">Read more</h2>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is very unclear. I'd suggest editing your post to ask a more specific question, if possible including some background to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's entirely possible.

You can use just plain old javascript:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div>Stuff inside a div.</div><div>another div!</div>';
```

Comment: But how do I do if I need to insert them a particular place?

Comment: @HelgiØsterPetersen ask a new question, asking how to add content using javascript to existing elements on a page - note though that people won't answer it without you showing that you've atleast tried something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible, you can accomplish this in several ways, this is just one way using standard Javascript. As you can see when the button is clicked I append a div to the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <button id='button' onclick='addDivs()'>Click me for magic</button>
    <script>
      var addDivs = function(){
        var h = document.createElement('div');
        h.innerHTML = 'I am a div';
        document.body.appendChild(h);
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function add_h3() {

  // creates a H3 element, class and html content

  var new_h3 = document.createElement('h3');

  new_h3.className = 'cls';

  new_h3.innerHTML = 'The <i>html text</i> content';

  // gets the reference tag

  var reference = document.getElementById('idiv');

  // add 'new_h3' before 'reference', inside body

  document.body.insertBefore(new_h3, reference);

}
--></script>
```

The reference element

Add H3